# What does Rick say in Nightmare on Elm Street 4 after he kicks off Freddy's glove?

Tags: dialogue, a-nightmare-on-elm-street-4

What does Rick say in *A Nightmare on Elm Street 4: The Dream Master* after he kicks off Freddy's glove?  Sounds like "tsai" but what does this signify in martial arts/karate?

Video clip:

Answer (score 2):

[The script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/A-Nightmare-on-Elm-Street-4.txt) doesn't have Rick say anything that sounds like "tsai". His scripted line after kicking off Freddy's glove is as follows:

> **Rick**: Hahaha.  You superhero.  How you gonna get me without your weapon?  You're dead meat.

I'm therefore assuming that the "tsai" was an unscripted noise that the actor happened to make, and doesn't actually mean anything.